# Issue with async.parallel

Tags: node.js, asynchronous

The problem, i belive, is somewhere aroung the async flow and incorrect parallel work for me...

So, i have two functions. The first function is updating the database variables (host, name, login, pass), it gets these values from the leveldb. Here's the code:

```
function refreshDbValues (whendone) {
    async.parallel([
        function (callback) {
            db.get('dbhost', function (err, value) {
                if(err) callback(err);
                dbhost = value;
                console.log('host ' + dbhost);
                callback(null);
            });
        },
        function (callback) {
            db.get('dbname', function (err, value) {
                if(err) callback(err);
                dbname = value;
                callback(null);
            });
        },
        function (callback) {
            db.get('dblogin', function (err, value) {
                if(err) callback(err);
                dblogin = value;
                console.log('user ' + dblogin);
                callback(null);
            });
        },
        function (callback) {           
            db.get('dbpass', function (err, value) {
                if(err) callback(err);
                dbpass = value;
                callback(null);
            }); 
        },

    ], whendone(null)); 
}
```

And the second function is serving mysql queries from router. And it has to execute the main code after the first function is complete. The code:

```
function handle_database(query, callback) { 

    refreshDbValues(function (err) {
        if(err) callback(err);
        console.log('just for test');

        var pool      =    mysql.createPool({
            connectionLimit : 100, //important
            host     : dbhost,
            user     : dblogin,
            password : dbpass,
            database : dbname,
            debug    :  false,
            multipleStatements: true
        }); 

        pool.getConnection(function(err,connection){
            if (err) {                  
                if(typeof(connection) != 'undefined') 
                    connection.release();
                return callback(err);
            }           

            connection.query(query,function (err, rows){
                connection.release();
                if(!err) return callback(null, rows);
                else console.log(err);
            });

            connection.on('error', function(err) {                      
                return callback("Error in connection database");    
            });
        });
    }); 
}
```

My output is as follows:

```
just for test
host ***
user ***
```

And i was awaiting 'just for test' to come last. Am i wrong in my logic, or something wrong with code?  Regards for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `async.parallel` definition is wrong - mainly, your callback that should be called when the parallel functions have finished is **called immediately**:

```
async.parallel([
    // Functions...
], whendone(null) /* <-- you are calling it right away! */)
```

Instead, you must pass the callback function as an argument without calling it:

```
async.parallel([
    // Functions...
], whendone /* No invocation */)
```

The purpose of the callback is that `async` may call it once it determines that all the parallel functions have completed. Your original code invoked the callback right away, and `async` instead received the return value of that callback as a callback, not the actual function.